# VBA - Multiple Sheet Array Print Sheets

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a few different arrays that are worksheets. What I want to build out is making this code print a group sheets via an array, where the "packages_to_print" array is equal to all the relevant array of sheets that need to printed. If this is not possible, is there a way to select multiple arrays to print?

This code doesn't give me an error, it just doesn't print anything to pdf.

Here's the relevant code. (The lender_package is the same as another variable because I have not built out the case statement for setting that variable to an array yet). Thank you in advance for your help.

```
Dim common_disclosures As Variant
Dim nh_disclosure As Variant
Dim provident_disclosures As Variant
Dim packages_to_print As Variant
Dim lender_package As Variant

common_disclosures = Array("Certification", "Responsible Use", "Security Procedures", "Acknowledgment", "FACTA Credit Score", "Anti-Steering")

nh_disclosures = Array("Loan Origination and Comp", "Rate Lock", "ECOA")
provident_disclosures = Array("MBFA")

lender_package = Array(provident_disclosures)

If subject_state <> "MA" Then
    packages_to_print = Array(common_disclosures, nh_disclosures, lender_package)
Else
    packages_to_print = Array(common_disclosures, lender_package)
End If

For j = 1 To (customerpackages * 2) 
     Worksheets(packages_to_print).Select  _ 

     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\users\" & environ_user & "\desktop\" & borrower_array(j - 1) & " disclosures.pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
Next j
```

Comment: You are not looping through the array elements. Where is j defined?

Comment: @AKapadia Please don't post code in comments (we cannot read that) instead [edit] your question and fix it there and delete the code comment. • Also it is unclear if you want all of your sheets in one PDF file or each sheet in a distinct file. Please clarify. • Also note that `ExportAsFixedFormat` is NOT printing! It is exporting to PDF. • Printing means a printer or at least a printer driver is involved (which is not the case here).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using array of arrays in `WorkSheets(..)` expression. Try joining the arrays as `packages_to_print` and it is running OK.

```
    If subject_state <> "MA" Then
    packages_to_print = Split(Join(common_disclosures, ",") & "," & Join(nh_disclosures, ",") & "," & Join(lender_package, ","), ",")
    Else
    packages_to_print = Split(Join(common_disclosures, ",") & "," & Join(lender_package, ","), ",")
    End If
```

Full Trial Code, may try it on any new workbook with 8-8 sheets

```
Sub test()
Dim common_disclosures As Variant
Dim nh_disclosures As Variant
Dim lender_package As Variant
Dim packages_to_print As Variant

    common_disclosures = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet4", "Sheet3", "Sheet2", "Sheet5")
    nh_disclosures = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet5")
    lender_package = Array("Sheet6", "Sheet8")

    subject_state = "MA"
    If subject_state <> "MA" Then
    packages_to_print = Split(Join(common_disclosures, ",") & "," & Join(nh_disclosures, ",") & "," & Join(lender_package, ","), ",")
    Else
    packages_to_print = Split(Join(common_disclosures, ",") & "," & Join(lender_package, ","), ",")
    End If

   Worksheets(packages_to_print).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Book1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        False

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code you provided input but did not work. I am receiving a "Run-time error 13" type mismatch error.

The current arrays "common_disclosures", "nh_disclosures" and "lender_packages are arrays of various worksheets. What I am trying to do is group all these arrays as one giant array so I can print the sheets all at once into one file.

My understanding of the split function is that it turns into a string array. Could this be the issue? I tried putting "Array" in front of the split code but that did not work either.

Comment: if you delete the line `provident_disclosures = Array("MBFA")` and directly use  `llender_package = Array("MBFA"),` I think code will work.. I posted the code only after successful trial taking "common_disclosures", "nh_disclosures" and "lender_packages  as arrays like `common_disclosures = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet4", "Sheet3")` and so on. **The main point avoid using array of arrays.in the expression `Worksheets(....)`**

Comment: Alternately may populate `packages_to_print` directly with sheet names like `packages_to_print= Array("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet4","Sheet6","Sheet9")`. However I am adding full code of my trial, so that you may modify it to your requirement or otherwise modify of your code

Comment: How would you avoid using array of arrays? I can do the packages_to_print array adding each necessary sheet but it's going to be a lot more conditional code and that's why I though doing array of arrays was the best route. Just wondering if you had any better ideas.

Comment: With current code making lender_package =Array ("MBFA") would solve the problem. Anyway providend disclosure  is not being ùsed.